# Remove by index on nested list

Tags: python-3.x, list, iteration

I have a nested list:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

I want to iterate over the list and return a new nested list with each list returned with one value missing. So:

```
new_x = [[2,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,3]]
```

I have this:

```
temp_list = []
y = 0
for i in x:
    temp_list += i.remove(y)
    y+=1
print(x)
```

But what's happening is each iteration is removing the indexed item so the list goes out of range.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
for count, i in enumerate(list):
    if len(i) > 0:
        del i[count]
print(list)
```

For each sublist it deletes the element with an index equal to the index of the sublist

```
>>>[[2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Each item in the original nested list is the same list, I want to return a new list that has each iteration of that with one element removed. So if there are 4 items of [1,2,3,4] it would return a new nested list with each item with a different removed index.

Comment: I'm still getting hung up, here's a clearer example of my issue:
https://repl.it/L0ee

Comment: Something is going on with the x = [v] * len(v). It works when you're just inputting your nested list directly, instead of creating it. My guess is that x ends up referencing v len(v) times, and when deleting an element from x, you end up deleting it from v, which affects the other references, which is why you're getting an error

Answer (score 1):

You have to use pop instead for remove. See this one:

```
In [46]: x = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]

In [47]: new_list = [lst for ind, lst in enumerate(x) if lst.pop(ind)]

In [48]: new_list
Out[48]: [[2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: when I try to run this, I get pop index out of range. It works if I have the list written out, but if you look at the image I capped you'll see for some reason it gives me an index error:
https://i.imgur.com/iNEn7f5.png

Comment: It is due to list is mutable object and whenever you delete the things is deletes from original list. Initialize the variable again and run it. You won't get error.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, could you explain how to reinitialize the variable? You've been monumentally helpful.

Comment: Make another variable using deepcopy of original variable. https://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php

Comment: I'm wholly lost, how would that help? If you have a minute can you please show me how to add, because every time I try, I still get an index error.

Comment: from copy import deepcopy and the use new_sequence = deepcopy(sequence) and use new_sequence instead of sequence

Comment: I still get the exact same error. I have the module imported fine, and I created the new variable, but I get the same error.

Comment: Just check once that your x value is equal to this one or not by printing x value. [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

Comment: Instead of going back and forth, because I clearly do not understand what you mean, is there any chance you can show me? I really appreciate you spending your time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]

for i in range(0,len(x)):
    for j in range (0,len(x)):
        if(i==j):
            del(x[i][j])
print(x)
new_x = [[2,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,3]]
```

**del(x[i][j]) is used to delete by index from list**

Comment: x returns an empty list for some reason.

Comment: It is working fine for me and giving the desired output as condition (i==j) will remove only the selected elements, hence the list will not be empty.

Comment: Execute the code by taking dummy values of x(i.e x = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]) see if the code executes by giving desired output

Comment: It does if I explicitly make that the value for x. But if I iterate over the x value I create with:
for i in sequence:
    x += [sequence]
I get an index error.

Comment: I think the 1st part of the function(i.e making nested) list has errors which cause out of index problem.

Comment: I've been racking my brain trying to resolve it, but I can't seem to sort it out, any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, the environment on which you are executing code is not treating the list as nested(as if you execute del(x[0][0]) the 1st element from every sublist is removed).

Comment: Here's the updated repl.it:
https://repl.it/L0ee

I'm at such a loss as to how to resolve this error

Comment: It does, but not if the list is generated from another list. 
I get the indexing error if the list is created like this:
x = [sequence] * len(sequence)

It generates the same list, and if you compare your x value and mine they are the same, but one is treated vastly different than the other for some reason I can't figure out.